# CORS saying header is not present while it is... Does anyone know a fix?

Tags: cors, http-headers

So I keep getting this error while trying to get data from https://geo.leefbaarometer.nl/.

[image]

When I check into the headers set by the domain it contains the headers...

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I have been on this for 3 days now and I can't seem to find the solution. I does work with the ALLOW-CORS extension but it is not practical for everyone to just install an extension for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header says which domains are allowed to load this resource. You’ve shown that it allows it’s own domain to load that resource - but not your domain.

You’ve not explained how you’ve verified the header is there? I’d guess not based on the request you’re not making since it says the header is not set at all?

So it’s not sufficient that the header is present, it must return the origin of the requesting page. And this may change depending on which origin makes the request so cannot be depended on by checking an alternative request.